# What is the best way to load ASP.Net usercontrols via JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-ajax

What is the best way to emit an asp.net usercontrol back to the browser based on a JSON request?

So far I have a web service which creates the user control and sends it back to the browser.  However when I post back the whole page, I get an error about "the state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."

Considering I'm new to Json, I'm going to guess I'm doing it wrong.  What's the best way?

Should I just turn off view state validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: turn off view state validation.