# interview question - how to loop through an array with a different starting point?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say you have the string "This is a test"

I pass it to method zee, like ("This is a test", 1)
and want "test This is a";

I pass it to method zee, like ("This is a test", 2)
and want "a test This is";

the number can exceed the total words in variable. If it does it should loop around.

I started with....

```
public static string zee(string origString, int i)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.AddRange(origString.Split(' '));

    // not sure here - 
    for (int c = i; c < (list.Count + i); c++)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", list[c]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is something you should take some time to work out on your own.  It's not a complicated question and would probably be a good learning experience to experiment with different ways to solve.

Comment: Any reason you're using `ArrayList` rather than `List<T>`? It's 2010 :)

Comment: @Jon, in fact it's the end of 2010. This makes things even worse with C# 5.0 knocking at the door :-)

Comment: @Chris Lively: Interesting angle on a Q&A forum. "not complicated" is relative to experience level. Would you like somebody to tell you to figure out your next ASP.NET question on your own, or are you asking because you need help with it? For example, I think you could have figured this one out on your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587678 In fact you kind of did.

Comment: @John K: You'll notice on my question I gave a potential answer and was just looking for a better way, then I waited 19 months to answer it myself and close the question.  However, here we have someone that based on their previous Q&A on this site should be able to solve this particular problem within a few minutes.  Given the recent rash of interview questions and the sheer number of emails I've received lately asking if I'm looking for a job based off of finding me on this site I have to question the intent here.

Comment: @Chris Lively: I don't doubt you're in high demand based on 2.25 years of SO rep, however back to the question at hand: a teaching, mentoring or leading approach is good. This question has merit in and of itself despite us making judgements or guesses about author. By FAQ standards, nothing wrong with the question - it will prove useful to visitors and contributes positively to the embodiment of knowledge that's SO. I trust the author will feel comfortable asking other questions: the community has stepped up and deemed the question good as shown by answers and positive feedback.

Comment: BTW Chris, despite our different approaches to policing questions and users, I know you're a smart guy as evidenced by your involvement in the community, and I'm also taking this moment to say I've always liked your Avatar logo. Very catchy.

Comment: @John K: Thanks about the logo, I had 99designs.com do it.  After thinking about it further, you're probably right about this instance.  And I have to admit the number of different approaches to this problem did make it an interesting question... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int j=0; j < list.length; j++){
    int idx = (j + i) % list.length;
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} " , list[idx]);
}
```

Mostly like Brent Arias's solution, but I think a for loop is more readable, less likely to go infinite.

```
    public static string zee(string origString, int i)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.AddRange(origString.Split(' '));

        for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            int idx = (j + i) % list.Count;
            sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", list[idx]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: ha, ironic! this will loop infinitely. might want to add a j++ to the loop ;)

Comment: If Mike will add the j++, I will 'up' this answer.  I think it is the cleanest of them all.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd solve it.

```
    private static string f(string s, int start)
    {
        var arr=s.Split(' ');
        start %= arr.Length;

        var res=arr.Skip(arr.Length - start).ToList();
        res.AddRange(arr.Take(arr.Length - start));
        return string.Join(" ", res);
    }
```

I tried writing a one liner with linq but I don't see how to combine 2 lists. `Union` and `Join` aren't what I need.

Comment: `.Concat` will combine two sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried it, but I think this would do it:

```
i %= list.Length;
int index = i;
do {
  index %= list.Length;
  sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", list[index]);
while (++index != i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd solve it using strings.

```
    public static string zee(string origString, int i)
    {
        string[] splitStr = origString.Split(' ');
        string newStr = "";

        // Not sure what you meant by wrap around but this should
        // do the trick.
        i %= splitStr.Length;

        for (int j = (splitStr.Length - i); j < splitStr.Length; j++)
            newStr += splitStr[j] + " "; // Add spaces taken by split :(

        for (int j = 0; j < (splitStr.Length - i); j++)
            newStr += splitStr[j] + " ";

        return
            newStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an abomination trying to cram as much into one line as possible:

```
static string zee(string sentence, int wordCount)
{
  var words = sentence.Split(' ');
  return string.Join(" ", new[] { words.Skip(words.Count() - wordCount), words.Take(words.Count() - wordCount) }.SelectMany(w => w).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: duh, `SelectMany`, I kept trying to remember how to combine 2 enumerables in place -.-

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there isn't a flatten method. So I tend to use the SelectMany(id) approach :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static string rearrange(string phase,int index)
{
    string[] words = phase.Split(' ');
    string[] newwords = new string[words.Length];

    int pointer = index;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length;i++ )
    {
        if(pointer>=words.Length)
        {
            pointer = 0;
        }
        newwords[i] = words[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    return string.Join(" ", newwords);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a homework question to me, but here is an efficient use of the .Net framework:

```
    private static string [] SplitWords(string s, int startWord)
    {
        string[] words = s.Split(' ');
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        output.AddRange(words.Skip(startWord).ToArray());
        output.AddRange(words.Take(startWord).ToArray());
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

There is absolutely no error checking in this function so you will have to modify it for production code but you get the idea.

Comment: That doesn't generate a sentence with spaces like the question asked.

Comment: Hardly efficient, you're creating 3 arrays in addition to the resulting string (assuming you read the requirements again and fix it). It's maintainable though!

Comment: @OJ I'm sure you can figure out how to make a sentence with spaces.  That's pretty trivial.  The point is the words are now ordered the way you want it.  @Blindy Maintainable is my goal.  I write production code in a large team environment.  The last think I want is someone asking me about some code I wrote 8 months ago.  Thanks for the compliment!  :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public string SetStart(int startAt)
{
    const string sentence = "this is a test so it is";

    var words = sentence.Split(' ');

    var x = (startAt > words.Count()) ? startAt%words.Count() : startAt;

    return string.Join(" ", words.Skip(x).Concat(words.Take(x)));            
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I got the modulus round the wrong way but it's fixed now :)